# Open keyboard directly in Unity 2018

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

This is happening with the input field in Unity 2018

Step 1: Here, we have a basic InputField

[image]

Step 2: When I click the field, one system input appears on the bottom

[image]

Step 3: After click that input the keyboard appears

[image]

How can I open the keyboard directly? From step 1 to 3

Answer (score 0):

Use [`TouchScreenKeyboard.Open()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard.Open.html).

Here is some code from documantation :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
public string stringToEdit = "Hello World";
private TouchScreenKeyboard keyboard;

// Opens native keyboard
void OnGUI()
{
    stringToEdit = GUI.TextField(new Rect(10, 10, 200, 30), stringToEdit, 30);

    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 50, 200, 100), "Default"))
    {
        keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default);
    }
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 150, 200, 100), "ASCIICapable"))
    {
        keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.ASCIICapable);
    }
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 250, 200, 100), "Numbers and Punctuation"))
    {
        keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.NumbersAndPunctuation);
    }
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 350, 200, 100), "URL"))
    {
        keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.URL);
    }
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 450, 200, 100), "NumberPad"))
    {
        keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.NumberPad);
    }
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 550, 200, 100), "PhonePad"))
    {
        keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.PhonePad);
    }
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 650, 200, 100), "NamePhonePad"))
    {
        keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.NamePhonePad);
    }
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 750, 200, 100), "EmailAddress"))
    {
        keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.EmailAddress);
    }
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 850, 200, 100), "Social"))
    {
        keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.Social);
    }
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 950, 200, 100), "Search"))
    {
        keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.Search);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It is happening the same even with the GUI.TextField. Maybe it's because of the Android version